# Open solution that contains long file paths

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

After [building Bootstrap v4-alpha](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/) with `npm`, Visual Studio can no longer open my project, because the file paths are too long. It just hangs.

Bower installs bootstrap here:

`C:\Users\BigFont\Documents\GitHub\2015-113MH\webapp\src\webapp\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap`

That's fine. The problem arises after building bootstrap with `npm`. After deleting the `bootstrap` directory, Visual Studio can open the project, but I do not want to delete the directory.

How can we use Visual Studio with long path names?

## Edit

My current workaround is to use Visual Studio Code, because it can handle long file paths.

Answer (score 2):

I have resorted to creating folders at the root of my C:\ drive. I also use 7zip to delete folders to get around the 'file path too long' errors. You can open 7zip, click on the folder you want to delete and hit the Shift+Del keys.

NPM 2.0 creates nested folders that are very deep. Consider upgrading to NPM 3.0 as this fixes this problem and tries to create a folder structure that is as flat as possible.

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 RTM, it comes with NPM 2.0. NPM 3.0 will not be released with VS until the next update. You can still install NPM 3.0 but it is a little more involved. See [this](http://www.ageofascent.com/reduce-node_modules-recursion-long-paths-asp-net-5/) blog post for a step by step guide to install.